# Cannot mount ext4 with user permissions

Tags: permissions, mount

I have a disk, that has only one primary partition and that I want to be mount with permissions of the user for the contained files.

The mount point has the following permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 myself myself 4096 Jul 10 11:37 hdd4p1
```

The /etc/fstab contains the following entry:

```
/dev/sdd1   /home/myself/hdd4p1   ext4    rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user,users,async  0   2
```

But when I mount it with:

```
mount hdd4p1
```

It changes the ownership of the mount point to root:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 10 12:31 hdd4p1/
```

I have also tried default mount options and mounting with sudo, but it also changed the ownership to root.

Answer (score 1):

I myself had attemped this. And all you have to do is use the `sudo chown <user>:<group> -R /your/mountpoint`.If you would to mount to FAT32 filesystem, then you would need to change your /etc/fstab file.

Comment: I recommend making the stackexchange account next time.

Comment: I tried changing first the ownership recursively, but it did not help.

Comment: Did you mount the filesystem as readonly? That could be a problem. Also notice the `sudo` before the command.

Comment: If you think somebody solved the question, please click the tick below number of votes. (do not accidentally downvote the answer).

Comment: Sorry it's `sudo chown -R <user>:<group> /your/mountpoint` my bad.